# How to set labels for series in the stacked column chart in google sheets api from console application using google sheets api

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to create a stacked column chart with labels on each series in the google sheets using console application (so using google sheets api). From google sheets it's possible to create a label for each of series when you are setting up chart. But how to create them from code outside the google sheets document?

So I even create these labels in the google sheets document manually and then tried to find them from code, I found this chart but I didn't see anything about these labels.

Can you help me with this, please.